# what is the different about psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary python package

Tags: python-3.x

Today I found the python connect postgresql have psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary package, which one should I choose? what is the difference with the two package? seems no one talk about the diff about it.Seems psycopg2 are hard to install because of the dependencies. psycopg2-binary easy to install but weak with the ability.

Comment: `seems no one talk about the diff about it`: What about the [official documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary)?

Comment: And also here: https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/ where it says: The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources.

Comment: for the "why"... https://web.archive.org/web/20201111224247/https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between the two is that

- the binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources, whereas
- building psycopg requires a few prerequisites (a C compiler, some external development library packages)

Read more at [psycopg2 documentation on Python's Package Index (PyPI) projects website](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/)